# Trigger a UIPress programmatically with tvOS

Tags: ios, swift, tvos

I am trying to trigger a UIPress on my button in tvOS programmatically so that I can get the same animation a user receives when they click on a button. I have tried this:

```
// This is Swift 3 but a Swift 2 answer or even Objective-C is fine
button.sendActions(for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
```

The command performs a click on the button, but the animation of the focused button being pressed down is not performed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could animate the `UIButton`. You should use `.PrimaryActionTriggered` instead of `.touchUpInside` also. For example:

```
let animationDuration = 0.2
let focusedScaleFactor: CGFloat = 1.2
UIView.animateWithDuration(animationDuration, animations: {
    button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(focusedScaleFactor, focusedScaleFactor)
    }) { (finished) in
        UIView.animateWithDuration(animationDuration, animations: {
            button.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
        }) { (finished) in
            button.sendActions(for: .PrimaryActionTriggered)
        }
}
```

Comment: But isn't its default transform the identity transform? Nothing will animate.